In Identity Server, How to silently re-sign in an already logged session?
I had a configuration client + handler that worked only with cookies.
I have many users already logged with that cookies
That configuration didn't emit tokens, then I changed the client + handler to achieve that.
----- On Identity Server project
    new Client
    {
        // new lines
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        RequirePkce = false
    },

------On Client handler
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

------On Client handler
    private Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext arg)
    {
        // new line
        arg.HttpContext.Items.Add("JwtSecurityTokenUsedToCallWebAPI", arg.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

After these changes my users now have access tokens and I can access to it using: await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") but I need to log in the user.
If I try to call await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") with an already logged user, it will still return null.
I can't logout all the users or ask them to log out and then log in. I guess I need to silently refresh the session of logged users. How can I do that?
